# Creating account

Tags: logging, setup

I'm trying to setup an account with ubuntu one and the software ask to type a word to continue, but that word is not visible, then when I click on create account, the software hangs on "creating account, please wait"
What is the problem?

Comment: might be due to slow internet connectivity

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot see the image you can report a bug in [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/),  apparently there are already reports about this [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/985584) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sso-client/+bug/1193141). You can say that this affects you too (green line under the bug title).

Alternatively you can get it going creating your account online [here](https://one.ubuntu.com/) and then entering your account in the software on your computer.